# ARM Cortex-A9 NEON and VFP

Tags: floating-point, vectorization, neon, cortex-a, arm-none-eabi-gcc

I am using ARM Cortex-A9 (zynq7000) and I want to enable the neon SIMD but **not** to use it for floating points unless specified.

When compiled by arm-none-eabi-gcc with following fpu options (seperately) :

1. mfpu=vfpv3 -mfloat-abi=softfp ,
2. mfpu=neon-vfpv3 -mfloat-abi=softfp,
3. mfpu=neon -mfloat-abi=softfp,

the binaries 1 & 2 are different. But 2&3 are the same (vectorization not enabled),  
I am using -Og for optimization. ( -Og does not enable Vectorize options)

How can I make sure that all floating points are done in VFP, not the NEON when I use the option mfpu=neon-vfpv3?

According to the ARM Architecture Reference Manual, NEON and VFP support similar Instructions, which makes it difficult to distinguish the difference just by checking disassembly.

Moreover, I am planning to use  #pragma GCC ivdep for the loops and functions that I need to vectorize, and what would be the appropriate compiler flags to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compiler will never use any `neon` instruction unless auto vectorization is enabled or enforced via intrinsics.

Even though `neon` and `vfp` instructions look similar, they even operate in a different mode each.

There are a few instructions shared by `vfp` and `neon` on `armv7` (mostly memory related), but they shouldn't be of any concern.

Why don't you post the disassemblies?

Comment: Thank you, However, It is difficult to post the disassemblies online. I checked with the [link]https://godbolt.org/ and realized -Og option prevents GCC from vectorizing even if free-vectorization is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

**-mfpu=**

- In GCC(arm) when the `-mcpu=cortex-a9` or `-march=armv7-a` is set the
  option `mfpu=neon-vfpv3` and `mfpu=neon` are identical.

  ‘+neon’
  https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/ARM-Options.html

**-mfloat-abi=**

- ***soft***: VFP is not used and uses ARM Calling Convention
- ***softfp***: VFP is used but uses ARM Calling Convention ( ARM R registers are used to
  pass parameters to functions)
- ***hard***: VFP is used and Calling Convention is specific to the H/W ( along with ARM R registers VFP/NEON S and D registers are used to pass parameters to functions.
  S/D registers are used for floating-point parameters called by value)
  ​

**Floating Point operations on NEON(SIMD)**

- Unless the option ​ `funsafe-math-optimizations`  is set in GCC,
  Neon is NOT used for Floating-Point operations. (Neon does not
  follow IEEE 754 )

**vfp and neon instructions in disassembly:**

in case of vmov,

- The vfp uses only `vmov.f32` and `vmov.f64`
- neon uses vmov.i64, `vmov.i32`, and so on.

​
**Loop Vectorization**

- For Loop Vectorization `-ftree-vectorize` and `-O2` or `-O3` Optimization
  Option can be used

  When `-Og` Optimization is used Loops may not get vectorized automatically
- [vectorization of loops with neon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hAJ81.png)